# Parsing xpath with python

Tags: python, xpath, lxml, lxml.html

I'm trying to parse a web page that contains this:

```
<table style="width: 100%; border-top: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 1px solid black;">
<tr>
 <td colspan="2"
     style="border-top: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 1px solid black; background-color: #f0ffd3;">February 20, 2015</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td style="border-top: 1px solid gray; font-weight: bold;">9:00 PM</td>
 <td style="border-top: 1px solid gray; font-weight: bold">14°F</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid gray;">Clear<br />
  Precip:
  0 %<br />
                                Wind:
                    from the WSW at 6 mph
 </td>
 <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid gray;"><img class="wxicon" src="http://i.imwx.com/web/common/wxicons/31/31.gif"
       style="border: 0px; padding: 0px 3px" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td style="border-top: 1px solid gray; font-weight: bold;">10:00 PM</td>
 <td style="border-top: 1px solid gray; font-weight: bold">13°F</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid gray;">Clear<br />
  Precip:
  0 %<br />
                                Wind:
                    from the WSW at 6 mph
 </td>
 <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid gray;"><img class="wxicon" src="http://i.imwx.com/web/common/wxicons/31/31.gif"
       style="border: 0px; padding: 0px 3px" /></td>
</tr>
```

(it continues with more rows and ends with [/table]

```
tree = html.fromstring(page)
table = tree.xpath('//table/tr')
for item in table:
    for elem in item.xpath('*'):
        if 'colspan' in html.tostring(elem):
                print '*', elem.text
        elif elem.text is not None:
            print elem.text,
        else:
            print
```

somewhat works. It does not get the text following the [br /] and it's far from elegant.  How do I get the missing text?  In addition, any suggestions for improving the code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using [`.text_content()`](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#html-element-methods)?

> .text_content(): Returns the text content of the element, including the text content of
>   its children, with no markup.

```
table = tree.xpath('//table/tr')
for item in table:
    print ' '.join(item.text_content().split())
```

`join()`+`split()` here help to replace multiple spaces with a single one.

It prints:

```
February 20, 2015
9:00 PM 14Â°F
Clear Precip: 0 % Wind: from the WSW at 6 mph
10:00 PM 13Â°F
Clear Precip: 0 % Wind: from the WSW at 6 mph
```

---

Since you want to merge time-line with a precip-line, you can iterate over `tr` tags but skipping those containing `Precip` in the text. For every time-line, get the following tr sibling to get the precip-line:

```
table = tree.xpath('//table/tr[not(contains(., "Precip"))]')
for item in table:
    text = ' '.join(item.text_content().split())
    if 'AM' in text or 'PM' in text:
        text += ' ' + ' '.join(item.xpath('following-sibling::tr')[0].text_content().split())

    print text
```

Prints:

```
February 20, 2015
9:00 PM 14Â°F Clear Precip: 0 % Wind: from the WSW at 6 mph
10:00 PM 13Â°F Clear Precip: 0 % Wind: from the WSW at 6 mph
```

Comment: Much nicer!  Is there a good way identify if a line is a the date line, time line or other line (using xpath, not parsing the contents)?  If nothing else, I'd like to merge each time line with its clear precip line.

Comment: @foosion for a date line - I would follow the EAFP principle and try to load the contents with `datetime.strptime()` and handle `ValueError` - if no error - it is a date line. For a time line I think you can just search for `PM` or `AM` word inside the contents. Looks like other lines start with "Clear Precip"..

Comment: @foosion let me provide you with a sample, give me a minute.

Comment: alecxe I know how to do that. I was hoping there was a way to do it with xpath rather than parsing the text to see if it's a date or a time or other. For example, the dates are part of [td colspan="2"]

Comment: @foosion ok, but see the updated, may give you an idea about what I'm trying to say.

Comment: @foosion as for a date line, you are right - we can check if there is a `td` child with `colspan="2"`, like this: if `item.xpath('.//td[@colspan="2"]'):`